# Cloth digitizer! Making 3d models of real Cloths

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, hardware

I have this project of mine that I'm working on. It's for a clothing store, He need all his clothes to be available as 3d objects on the PC for different purposes later on.

I've been doing some research and I guess the only possible way is to get a model that wear each cloth, she stands on a board that will rotate in one way and a camera will.be taking shots at different angles.

I might be complicating stuffs but I need to know if there exist any other techniques for achieving this.

I don't mind any idea even if it requires electronics. Some hints will be helpful.

Comment: A laser scanner, but this might be to much effort

Comment: I added a hardware tag, as there is no way you get this info into your program without a sort of scanning device. There are laser scanners and something called white light projection. Both seem to be way to expensive for "a project of mine", but maybe you get some ideas there.

Comment: With the correct lightning and a font / back picture, might the concept of a height map work?

Comment: http://hardware.slashdot.org/story/13/03/13/1640241/point-and-shoot-3d-modeling-video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are searching for is a program called reconstructMe
here's [the link](http://reconstructme.net/).

what you need is a Kinect.
some other programs are also possible [simple google search](https://www.google.nl/search?q=kinect+scanning&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3anl%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_rn=5&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=wwZ9arYyN-BnruN4zF5znw&pq=kinect%20scanning&cp=16&gs_id=3t&xhr=t&q=kinect+scanning+software&es_nrs=true&pf=p&client=firefox-a&hs=Ni3&rls=org.mozilla%3anl%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&oq=kinect+scanning+&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZWU&fp=8d3af1e5b12e0f78&biw=826&bih=878)

I hope this helps!

**edit:**

if you want to do thing yourself, you might want to take a look at point-cloud-library here. It does require some C++ coding, I am working on a C# version though, so for more info on the wrapping you can msg me.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I guess the kinect can do the job. I will give it a test later on.